# How to use Solr copyfield to copy a value and modify it before storing it

Tags: xml, solr

First let me begin by saying that I am a total noob when it comes to configuring Solr (I am using version 3.6.2 by the way). I would like to do is create a new field by copying a value from another field and then modifying it before it gets stored. In this particular case I would like to copy the year field (which contains a year as a string ie 2014) and then convert that into a proper date value compatible with Solr's DateField.

I thought of using copyfield as a method to accomplish this but I am not sure how to do the conversion part of it. This is what I have so far:

```
<field name="dc.date" type="text_en" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
<copyField source="dc.date" dest="dc.date_dt"/>
<field name="dc.date_dt" type="date" multiValued="false" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

How would one go about accomplishing this?

Comment: Note that copyField declarations can only come after all the field declarations, and that field declarations are nested with its own tag. So your example should look more like this:
<fields>
  <field name="dc.date" ... />
  <field name="dc.date_dt" ... />
</fields>
<copyField source="dc.date" dest="dc.date_dt"/>

Answer (score 0):

You can't. `copyField` is a convenient declaration that saves you from having to set the same value for two different fields when adding or updating a document.

So when you add or update documents, you will have to do the date transformation yourself and then set `dc.date` and `dc.date_dt`.

Comment: That is good to know. So how would I accomplish this? Would I need to use an xslt?

Comment: @user5013 For the schema, you can use the same field declarations as above. Just leave out the copyField.